# Android: Background Service to Simulate Touches in Any App Underneath a Window

Tags: android, touch, android-5.0-lollipop

I have a `Service` that can draw a `Canvas` on top of all applications using a `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` which contains a custom `View`.

My `Service` and custom `View` both implement `View.OnTouchListener`

The `onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev){}` method of the Service returns `true` while the custom View returns `false`. This allows me to display my custom `View` on top of all apps and still interact with the underlying `Activity`. This part works.

I also want the `Service` to simulate a touch event in the specified coordinates in the current `Activity` that is underneath the `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW`.

I was hoping I could call `View.dispatchTouchEvent(...)` on the custom View and because `onTouch(...)` returns `false`, the touch event would get passed on to the underlying `Activity`. It does not work.

**How can I simulate touch events in any Activity in this situation?**

I have used code from the following sources...

Draw a canvas on top of all applications:

http://www.piwai.info/chatheads-basics/

[Draw an Android canvas on top of all applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391604/draw-an-android-canvas-on-top-of-all-applications)

Passing touches to underlying app:

[How can I interact with elements behind a translucent Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635934/touch-through-translucent-app)

Simulating touches:

[How to simulate a touch event in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4396059/how-to-simulate-a-touch-event-in-android)

Comment: AFAIK, you can't, for obvious security reasons, except probably on rooted devices. Even the accessibility APIs don't support this AFAICT. Allowing arbitrary apps to fake input to other apps would be a major security hole.

Comment: Is it at least possible to simulate touch input in apps that are part of the Android OS if the views are accessed specifically? Can I do something like getView().dispatchTouchEvent(..)?

Comment: "Can I do something like getView().dispatchTouchEvent(..)?" -- no, because the `View` is in another process, not yours.

Comment: Is there an alternative way to interact with a view automatically?

Comment: You can use whatever the accessibility APIs offer you. You can probably do much more on a rooted device, but I don't even really know where to point you for what to do in that case.

Comment: CommonsWare: Could you make this an answer, please? I will accept it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635934/touch-through-translucent-app

Comment: How does this app do it : Airplane Mode - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.floriandraschbacher.airplanemode.free

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't, for obvious security reasons, except probably on rooted devices. Even the accessibility APIs don't support this AFAICT. Allowing arbitrary apps to fake input to other apps would be a major security hole.

If your objective is to do this during testing, instrumentation testing allows you to simulate touch events in your own app.

Comment: can I use instrumentation in a background service? My device is rooted. I tried that, I got no error, but how can I make sure that the view was touched if the touch was sent from a background service? Thanks.

Comment: Is it perhaps possible these days? Maybe via accessibility APIs ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper: AFAIK, the accessibility APIs still do not allow delivery of specific touch events.

Comment: @CommonsWare How do eye tracking apps do it (this for example: http://www.androidcentral.com/eye-tribe-gaze-tracking-enables-finger-free-fruit-ninja-android ) ? Via hardware that uses adb commands? Or maybe Samsung-only APIs, as someone wrote me a long time ago about TeamViewer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20391295/878126 ? And what about key events? I know that there are many apps that allow emulating a global back key  (like this one: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.app58us.backkey ) . How do they work?

Comment: @CommonsWare This can help for both people with disability, and for UI automation tools for power users and developers. Anyway, I've made a request: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=231758